# Next.js Navbar gives a warning of Target Element not found when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, navigation, react-navigation

I am currently working on a next.js app, which contains a connect wallet button found to the right of the navbar, with the navigation links to the left of the navbar.

This is what it looks like currently

[image: Image of Navbar]

This is the code for the NavBar.jsx react page

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link , animateScroll as scroll, scroller} from 'react-scroll'

import { MenuIcon, XIcon } from '@heroicons/react/outline';
import { navLinks } from '../pages/data';


const Navbar = ({ initHashconnect }) => {
  const [nav, setNav] = useState(false)
  const handleClick = () => setNav(!nav)

  const handleClose = () => setNav(!nav)


  return (
    <div className='navbar navbar-expand-lg shadow-md py-2 bg-white relative flex items-center w-full justify-between'>
      <div className='px-2 flex justify-between items-center w-full h-full'>
        <div className='flex items-center'>
          <h1 className='text-3xl font-bold mr-4 sm:text-4xl'>P2A</h1>
          <nav>
            <ul className='hidden md:flex'>
              <li><Link to="/home" activeClass="active" spy={true} smooth={true} duration={500}>Home</Link></li>
              <li><Link to="/solutions" activeClass="active" spy={true} smooth={true} offset={-200} duration={500}>Solutions</Link></li>
              <li><Link to="/projects" activeClass="active" spy={true} smooth={true} offset={-50} duration={500}>Projects</Link></li>
              <li><Link to="about" activeClass="active" spy={true} smooth={true} offset={-100} duration={500}>About us</Link></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <div className='hidden md:flex pr-4'>
          <button className='px-8 py-3' onClick={initHashconnect}>Connect Wallet</button>
        </div>
        <div className='md:hidden mr-4' onClick={handleClick}>
          {!nav ? <MenuIcon className='w-5' /> : <XIcon className='w-5' />}

        </div>
      </div>

      <ul className={!nav ? 'hidden' : 'absolute bg-zinc-200 w-full px-8'}>
        <li className='border-b-2 border-zinc-300 w-full'><Link onClick={handleClose} to="home" smooth={true} duration={500}>Home</Link></li>
        <li className='border-b-2 border-zinc-300 w-full'><Link onClick={handleClose} to="solutions" smooth={true} offset={-200} duration={500}>About</Link></li>
        <li className='border-b-2 border-zinc-300 w-full'><Link onClick={handleClose} to="projects" smooth={true} offset={-50} duration={500}>Support</Link></li>
        <li className='border-b-2 border-zinc-300 w-full'><Link onClick={handleClose} to="about" smooth={true} offset={-100} duration={500}>Platforms</Link></li>
        <li className='border-b-2 border-zinc-300 w-full'><Link onClick={handleClose} to="pricing" smooth={true} offset={-50} duration={500}>Pricing</Link></li>

        <div className='flex flex-col my-4'>
          <button className='bg-transparent text-indigo-600 px-8 py-3 mb-4'>Connect Wallet</button>
          <button className='px-8 py-3'>Submit A project</button>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

This is the Layout.jsx react page where the Navbar component is exported to

```
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import { initHashconnect } from '../utils/hashconnectService';

export default function Layout({ children }) {
    return (
        <>
          <Navbar initHashconnect={initHashconnect} />
          <main>{children}</main>
        </>
      )
}
```

This is the _app.js page where the Layout component is exported to and displayed on the live server

```
    import Layout from '../components/layout'
import '../styles/globals.css'
import Link from 'next/link'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return(
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps}/>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

However, whenever I try to click on any of the nav buttons on the dev server, I get this error that pops up.

[image: This happened when I clicked on the Solutions link button]

I am not sure why this is happening, as the links should be directing the users to the respective pages

Comment: Aren't you supposed to put a `<a>` tag in your Link

Comment: I tried having both with and without the <a> tag, both still threw the target element not found warning in the dev tools, Im not too sure what exactly that error means